# Custom cell of a ListView won't match parent width in API9

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

The problem is somehow related to API. In API 9+ the cells look perfectly which is **like this**:

[image]

**However on Android 2.3 it looks like this:**
[image]

**I can't find reason of that. Here is my cell layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/cell_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_cell"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    ...content here
</LinearLayout>
```

**And the list fragment layout:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >
    </ListView>
</FrameLayout>
```

The problem is for sure in the layout, since it displays wrong even in layout editor in Eclipse. How to make it work for all API's 9+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my god. It's always the bloody `FrameLayout`. I got advice for you. Don't use FrameLayout. Even if you think it fits, don't. It causes tons of troubles. For example, here when I changed main layout from `FrameLayout` to `LinearLayout` it works perfectly!